# How to update boolean value in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When a user comments on a post its approval is first saved as `false`, because the admin has to review his post and approve it.  I want it to change to approved after the admin has completed their review.

This is my initial code:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    $data = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data->setApproval(false);
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

    // $this->redirectToRoute("view_blog");
    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

After the Admin verifies user comments, he clicks the approve button, and then I do this:

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comment::class)->find($id);

$data = $post->getApproval();    

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$data->setApproval(true);        
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();
```

But, I'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function setApproval() on boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$data->setApproval(true);` with `$post->setApproval(true);`

It should be like.

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Comment::class)->find($id);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$post->setApproval(true);        
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: That should do it

Comment: Also, on update there is no need to persist the entity again.